# Pinescript: How to know order was placed (on the current candle) to apply an entry delay

Tags: pine-script

Sometimes I get a position to open and trigger Stop Loss on the same candle, or the other way around, when a SL hits and then enter a trade on the same candle. This is fine for the strategy I am trying to build.

However I would like to know how to identify the I am on a trade on those situations.

I attach an image to illustrate better.

[image]

On candle 1. I enter a Long. On candle 2 SL triggers.
I would like to then set a delay in candles (which I have already implemented) and postpone the next Long.

For that I am trying to get, on candle 1, a variable to tell I am on a trade.
I could use that in combination with `strategy.opentrades` and check if on candle 1 the variable tells I am on a trade. Then on candle 2 check if still this variable is on but `strategy.opentrades` is 0, then block the next long.

I have tried using `strategy.opentrades`, but in this case I have to wait 1 candle. I have also tried executing the script "after order is filled" and encapsulating all code with 2 ifs (one for `strategy.opentrades > 0` and the other for `strategy.opentrades == 0`)

So far I still can't identify the scenario and set the delay properly

Answer (score 0):

The condition `strategy.position_size[1]!=0 and strategy.position_size==0` can help to determinate that a position was closed at current bar.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, in this case candle 2 would not show position size to be 0 as the stop loss trigger and entered a new trade.

Comment: On the screenshot there are stop loss doesn open new position, it just closes existing one.